# Given absolute path, get relative path, which is relative to the cwd

Tags: node.js, path

Say my current working dir is `/home/oleg/foo`, and I have this filepath:

```
const p = '/home/oleg/foo/bar/baz';
```

I am looking to get:

```
const p1 = './bar/baz';
```

I assume we can use `require('path')` to do this, but not sure how.

Answer (score 0):

If I use this:

```
const path = require('path');
const cwd = process.cwd();
const p1 = path.relative(cwd, p);
```

then I get something like

```
'bar/baz/boop'
```

but I am looking for

```
'./bar/baz/boop'
```

so maybe the right way to do it is a simple case of:

```
const p1 = './' + path.relative(cwd, p);
```

Comment: I originally misread your qestion. Yes, that's right direction. Paths are normalized without leading `.`. `'./' +` - certainly not. It's `'.' + path.sep + path.relative(cwd, p)`. Notice that it will be denormalized if there's `..` already.